# How to Fix/Repair corrupt Firebird GDB/GBK file?

Tags: firebird, corrupt

We have corrupt Firebird GDB and GBK files. Here is the error when I try to open it :

```
Engine Error (code = 335544323):
file C:\..\xxxx.GDB is not a valid database
SQL Error (code = -922)
Connection authorization failure
```

How or is there any tools to fix the problem?

Comment: The error generally means that you are trying to open a file that is not a Firebird database, or that the header page of your database is nuked. I think it might also occur if you copied a Firebird database between platforms without using a backup and restore. You'll likely need professional help to repair the database (assuming it is even a Firebird database, and this is even repairable). You can try contacting [IBSurgeon/IB-aid](https://ib-aid.com/).

Comment: In any case, this is not really a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Consider asking it on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) instead.

Comment: I have used IBSurgeon for years.  It is successful most of the time.  And maybe you should consider a proper backup of your disk, maybe even an offsite backup.